# What method is used to apply this exterior wall treatment?

Tags: walls, painting

We have a summer house whose exterior walls need some repairs, but in order to keep the original look and texture of the walls, I need to find out what could be the method (and tools) used to achieve the look seen in the photos. It looks kind of like a layer of popcorns from the closeup, no sharp edges or corners in the texture. Is it possible to tell the method used from the photos below?

[image: general view]
general view

[image: close-up 2]
close-up

[image: general view 2]
general view (6 feet distance)

**Additional Note**

I have taken additional pictures of a damaged part of the coating, so that it could possibly give some more hints about how it was made:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture from 5-8 foot back? Do you know what year it was built? It looks like an older style textured stucco but hard to tell from these pics. In that scenario it is usually a dash brush or deck brush. Actual technique take some trial & error. Can add more if you add another pic.

Comment: The house was built in early 80's. I will take and post additional pictures soon...

Comment: @CoHusker I have added another photo that I took from approx 6 feet away. i also confirmed that it was built with this coating in early 80's...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **Pebble Dash**.  If you are in the UK it probably is.   You apply wet plaster to the wall then throw little stones at it (really, you throw them).  Then you paint with a sprayer. Because it's a little random it's not hard to hide repairs but you may need to paint the entire wall to do that.   Look on youtube for demonstrations.

They can also be unpainted like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The coating looks very even on the stucco /concrete homes that I have worked on to get that even coating they actually applied a coating that was loaded with sand. If the coating has areas that are flaking small or large they usually form a bubble removing all the loose material is important then matching the sand size and reapplying.